# how to automaticly upload videos to youtube whit DSM synology and youtube-upload

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, synology

I'm trying to automaticly upload video's to youtube on mine synology NAS (DS220+)
I've found this link to [tokland youtube-upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload).

All the steps on this github page I've done correctly (i think but obvious not :)
I think there is a auth problem whit Google and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or maybe there is a better way.

Steps I've taken:
-via SSH installed google-api-python-client and ofcourse youtube-upload-master.
-created a chanal and API credentials at youtube for clientsecrets.json
(Here I think I'm going wrong --> not shut what to put in the "Authorized redirect URIs" a.k.a. redirect_uris)
below you found mine client_secrets.json (ofcourse whitout the real client/project id's) but the redirect_uris and javascript_origins is legit (i think but posibly also the problem but realy don't know how to handle this)

```
 {
   "web":{
     "client_id":"client-id",
     "project_id":"project-id",
     "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
     "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
     "client_secret":"client-secret",
     "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"],
     "javascript_origins":["http://localhost"]
     }
```

}

In the end I was hoping ( and maybe not even posible but I'm new at this and needed a goal in this corona time) making a simple batch script to call this script when a file apears in a folder and upload it to a chanel in youtube.
batch script:

```
 youtube-upload \
   --title="test title" \
   --description="test description" \
   --category="Music" \
   --tags="mutter, beethoven" \
   --recording-date="2011-03-10T15:32:17.0Z" \
   --default-language="en" \
   --default-audio-language="en" \
   --client-secrets="/volume1/some/folder/client_secrets.json" \
  test.mp4
```

When I run the above code via SSH on the synology I'm getting a question to enter a verification code.
whish i must get from the link above the question to "read in" the access token ( I think , again I'm new and trying to understand this langues)

[image]

When I follow the link I'm getting this site from google instead a code :

[image: googleimg]

I'm realy stuck at this moment and open for some new insight.
All I want to do is upload a video to youtube in a scheduled automatic way from a synology NAS.
Doesn't sound very complicated when i started but couldn't find any good exmples to build on.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or does a better way to do this?

EDIT (for future reference) :

Afther some playing around and help from @stvar I installed a new secrets file:

```
{
  "installed":{
    "client_id":"someclientid",
    "project_id":"somecprjid",
    "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret":"somesecret",
    "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]
    }
  }
```

??? Afther this i got another error whish i thought i was creating ???? :

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/services/homes/usrname/.youtube-upload-credentials.json'
```

Comment: If you're running your app locally (on your computer) you have to setup your project to be of type *Desktop* within Google developers console. Your JSON client secrets file shows your project to be of type `"web"`; it should be `"installed"` instead.

Comment: @stvar thnx that totaly did the trick..
changed the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs settings to desktop en downloaded a new client_secrets.json.
did get verified whit the new link.
pasted the code i got there...
and..
new error : IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/services/homes/usrname/.youtube-upload-credentials.json'
whish i thougt i was creating whit this proces.....
did i something wrong?

Comment: Does your dir `/var/services/homes/usrname/` exist? If not, do enable the [User Home Service](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_user_advanced)

Comment: @stvar yesssss!!!!!! and no..... I din't had homes folder .... checked it.... and uploaded a video!!
many thanks!! now the tweaking begins :) wish settings to use as metadata

Comment: @stvar please consider post your comments as an answer and so the OP can vote and marked as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

give it a shot ytb_up based selenium all you need is login into your google account and get a cookie json

https://github.com/wanghaisheng/ytb-up
features YOU MAY NEED

1. proxy support

auto detect whether need a proxy
2. cookie support

for those multiple channels under same google account
3. schedule time publish

you can explictly specify a date and time for each video or you can set publish policy and daily public count,for example,daily count is 4,you got 5 videos,then first 4 will be published 1 day after the upload date ,the other 1 will be 2 days after the upload date
4. fix google account verify